# Error when sending an email c#

Tags: c#

I try to send an email (with gmail) in C#. I check the solutions I can find on google but it never works for me, I always have the error :

> SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The response from the server Was: 5.5.1 Authentication
>   Required.

This is an exampe of code :

```
string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
int portNumber = 587;
bool enableSSL = true;

string emailFrom = "*****@gmail.com";
string password = "*****";
string emailTo = "******@gmail.com";
string subject = "Hello";
string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
    mail.To.Add(emailTo);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the email account you are trying to send email through have two-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution which works for me. The solution proposed by [un-lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5195227/un-lucky)
was good but I need to configure gmail account.

So the code is :

```
        string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int portNumber = 587;
        bool enableSSL = true;

        string emailFrom = "****@gmail.com";
        string password = "*****";
        string emailTo = "****@gmail.com";
        string subject = "Hello";
        string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            mail.To.Add(emailTo);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
```

Moreover in your gmail account, you have to make this changes.

[gmail account changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4pdb.png)

Answer (score 0):

> The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) says that : Some SMTP servers require that the client be
>   authenticated before the server sends e-mail on its behalf. Set this
>   property to true when this SmtpClient object should, if requested by
>   the server, authenticate using the default credentials of the
>   currently logged on user. For client applications, this is the desired
>   behavior in most scenarios.

So you need to set `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` before assigning `Credentials`, So your code will looks like the following:

```
using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
{
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
    smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: I add the line I missed but I always have the Exception